# Unable to access spreadsheet which is published to the web from appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, publish, sharing

I've written a app script(web app) to access spreadsheet and display it's content based on search criteria.

[Web app should display content based on given name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tieqi.png)

It is working fine with my own gmail account. But when other users(given access for app script web app) tried this app they're seeing error as

"Exception: You do not have permission to access the requested document."  It is throwing an error when SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId) is executed.

By giving an explicit access(sharing with user) to the spreadsheet, he is able to access the data without any issue.
But as spreadsheet is already published to the web to access by anyone, why should it required again an explicit access to execute spreadsheet.

Is there way to access spreadsheet data without sharing it with the end user? Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Execute as "Me" should do it.

Comment: It is working for me but not for other users.

Comment: Hi there @Avinash! When you click on "*Deploy as web app*" you should be prompted with a menu where one option is "*Execute the app as:*". Could you please confirm that you have the value "*Me*" in that area as @TheMaster suggested?

Comment: Thanks for response... I've given access at "Execute the app as:" as "user accessing the web app", as this app is intended to be accessed by others also. So if I give only "Execute the app as:" as Me, I think it can't be accessed by anyone else except me. Please correct me if I understood wrongly.  As described in my issue... I'm(also other users) able to access the app script web app but the spreadsheet is not accessible which is already published to the web.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you published a web app that opens a certain Sheet. In the "*Deploy as web app*" menu (opened from the Apps Script editor and selecting `Publish ⮞ Deploy as web app`) you would have been asked to determine how to "*Execute the app as*". You can choose between these values:

- Me: every web app user will open the Sheet as yourself.
- User accessing the web app: every web app user will open the Sheet as themselves.

As a consequence of the second case, the users would need previous access to be able to open the Sheet. Since you want to give them access no matter what, I recommend to use the first option. Please, ask me any additional doubt.